# Pass function variable to label

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am struggling with Kivy framework for some time. I cannot find answer to my problem online.

I have two files: main.py and .kv file.
In main.py file I have function inside Boxlayout.

For example:

```
class Box(BoxLayout):

    def change(self):
            variable = 0

            while variable < 10:
                text = "Some text " + str(variable)
                variable += 1
```

As you can see, there is a string variable "text" and this variable is different on each loop.

Now in .kv file I have a label.
For example:

```
Box:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: butt
            text: ""
            on_press: root.change()
        Label:
            id: label_text
```

I would like button to run function change() and I would like see value of "text" variable displayed in label.
So after user click on button, he will see text changing on label:
"Some text 0", "Some text 1", "Some text 2".... "Some text 9".

I have tried to use label ID in main.py file like:

(inside change function)

```
label = self.ids['label_text']
self.count = str(variable)
label.text = "Some text " + self.count
```

but end up with nothing.
I think I could do this with "return text" at the end of function, but I don't want to pass only last "text" variable from the loop. I want label to change text when variable changes during loop.

Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

`from kivy.properties import StringProperty` and define your label's text as `label_text = StringProperty()` so it will be updated in the GUI when changed in your logic.
in your `.kv` file add `text: root.label_text` to the `Label` properties and in your `.py` file:

```
class Box(BoxLayout):
    label_text = StringProperty()

    def change(self):
            variable = 0
            while variable < 10:
                self.label_text = "Some text " + str(variable)
                variable += 1
```

this is the answer to your question regarding updating the label's text value in the GUI. But dont use loops like `while True` or the one you used in your code cause it will stop kivy's GUI thread from updating itself. Instead use kivy Clock (`from kivy.clock import Clock`) to schedule a task and run it in specific intervals so the GUI thread won't be blocked. Something like

```
class Box(BoxLayout):

    label_text = StringProperty()
    interval = 0.5  # Second
    offset = 0

    def change(self):
        # You ask the clock to update the label's value every self.interval (0.5) second
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label_text, self.interval)

    def update_label_text(self, dt):
        if self.offset < 10:
            self.label_text = "some_text" + str(self.offset)
            self.offset += 1
        else:
            # Finally ask the clock to forget about updating
            Clock.unschedule(self.event)
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem, but...it's still not 100% clear for me how this exactly work. Can you recommend some good kivy tutorial?

Comment: @Maciejjy It would be nice to accept and vote an answer if it works :)
Did you take this one? https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html

Comment: Of course. But I cannot vote up. Got some message that for user with less than 15 rep don't change post score.

Comment: That's fine. what about the tutorial? did you take it?

Comment: Just checking it. Seems nice and it cover what I need.Thanks!

Comment: Can you please take a look on another problem below?

Answer (score 0):

Still got some problems with displaying text in label. With short functions, everything seems fine but I have this function with lots of opening files, ifs and writing to database:

```
def add_to_base(self, dt):
    self.adding = "Adding to database..."
    with open("new_links.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            working on html here
            xxx = got list of string here
            for x in xxx:
                if ....
                    zzz = got another list with string
            for i in xxx:
                if
                 .
                 .
                Lots of elif's
            write element to database
            print("Added to databes")
            if element is last element:
                Clock.unschedule(self.event)
```

Of course this is not actual code, just model how it works.
I would like to display and update "self.adding" text from this function.
In .kv file I have label with text: self.adding property.
In run this add_to_base function with:

```
def update_base(self):
    self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.add_to_base, self.interval)
```

The problem is, that text is displayed on label but at the very end of this function. This function takes long time to finish (around 15 minutes to go trough elements and adding them to databse) and when function is finished, text is displayed. I would like to display this text on the very beginning.

Comment: The function `add_to_base()` is blocking the kivy GUI thread until it is done. As I said, avoid running such loops using `for` and `while` and use kivy Clock to schedule them for you. I suggest add all lines of your file to a `Queue()` then schedule an interval to read from that `Queue()` and operate on it rather than the one you did that blocks the GUI thread. read about python `Queue()`

Comment: Oh ok. So if we have very long function to end (like 15 minutes) then kivy.Clock cannot refresh any variable from this function faster than each 15 minutes? Interval in this case is not important because it's smaller than function time?

Comment: somehow, I mean break the task into smaller tasks and ask the clock do each task in intervals.